# Pivot a one-row dataframe so the column titles and values each become values in columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like the following in SQLite:

| Housing | Furniture | YardWork |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22.2 | 5.2 | 3.6 |

I want to pivot it so that it looks like the following:

| Task | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Housing | 22.2 |
| Furniture | 5.2 |
| YardWork | 3.6 |

How can I do this in SQLite, without explicitly listing out every column name?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `CROSS JOIN` as follows :

```
select 
  c.col as Task,
  case c.col
    when 'Housing' then Housing
    when 'Furniture' then Furniture
    when 'YardWork' then YardWork
  end as Time
from mytable t
cross join
(
  select 'Housing' as col
  union all select 'Furniture'
  union all select 'YardWork'
) c
```

This is to list only one column :

```
select 
      c.col as Task,
      case c.col
        when 'Housing' then Housing
      end as Time
    from mytable t
    cross join
    (
      select 'Housing' as col
    ) c
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cQ2vF5ryHQDpEb2eCrnvQY/0)

Comment: I asked if there was a way without listing all column names

Comment: To list any column just add it into the case when clause and on the cross join.